# How to convert dictionary key-value pairs to tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, data-conversion

Must convert this:

```
d = {"k1": ("v1"), "k2": ("v2"), "k3": ("v3")}
```

to this:

```
[('k1, v1'), ('k2, v2'), ('k2, v3')]
```

I tried this:

```
[(k, v) for k, v in d.items()]
```

But got this:

```
[('k1', ('v1')), ('k2', ('v2')), ('k3', ('v3'))]
```

Close, but I cannot have those extra parentheses.

Comment: If you are sure about the format, just use (k, v[0])

Comment: Note, `[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()]` should just be `list(d.items())`, which, if evaluated, gives me `[('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k1', 'v1')]`for the example you provided. Note also, your example of incorrect output, `[('k1', ('v1')), ('k2', ('v2')), ('k3', ('v3'))]` actually evaluates to `[('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3')]`. So what , **exactly** do you have?

Comment: Are you sure your dict isn't `{"k1": ("v1",), "k2": ("v2",), "k3": ("v3",)}`? Otherwise, those values should be strings, not tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {"k1": ("v1"), "k2": ("v2"), "k3": ("v3")}
print [(k, v) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Already returns

```
[('k3', 'v3'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k1', 'v1')]
```

(which is the same as actually doing `list(d.items())`)

---

Now, if your dictionary is actually

```
d = {"k1": ("v1",), "k2": ("v2",), "k3": ("v3",)}
```

then that would explain your output. In this case, you need to do

```
print [(k, v[0]) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d = {"k1": ("v1"), "k2": ("v2"), "k3": ("v3")}
new_data = list(d.items())
```

Output:

```
[('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
>>> d = {"k1": ("v1"), "k2": ("v2"), "k3": ("v3")}
>>> [(a,d[a]) for a in d]
[('k3', 'v3'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k1', 'v1')]
```

Comment: This is just an indirect way of doing `list(d.items())`,which the OP is already reporting they've tried.

Comment: Nop, `d[a]` is not a list (unlike unpacking `d.items()`), see my result.

Comment: Your code is **exactly equivalent**. Try doing `list(d.items()`.

Comment: Yes, the OP's problem definitely inadequately specified.

Answer (score 0):

Just index the string out of the tuple in your list comprehension, i.e.,

```
 [(k, v[0]) for k, v in d.items()]
```

This gives

```
 [('k3', 'v'), ('k2', 'v'), ('k1', 'v')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
d = {"k1":("v1"), "k2":("v2"), "k3":("v3")}
tuple1 = d.items()
    
print(list(tuple1 ))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).